# How to show flatpages with a single URL in Django?

Tags: django

I am trying to namespace Flatpages in Django. I included `/pages/` in URLConf and added one URL `/help/` in Django Admin Sites module. However, the page is loading with '/help/' and '/pages/help/' both URLs. I am trying to stop this behaviour and only load the page with `/pages/help/`. How is this possible?

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...

    url(r'^pages/', include('django.contrib.flatpages.urls')),
]
```

[image: Django Admin panel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have the fallback middleware installed in your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` setting:

```
'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware'
```

Remove it, and then it will only work on the prefix you have specified.